# Date Range Between 2 Different Field In ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to fetch document between two date according to start and end date.

This is Mapping:

```
PUT data 
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": { 
      "properties": { 
        "product_code": {"type": "keyword"},
        "color_code": {"type": "keyword"},
        "warehouse_id": {"type": "short"},
        "stock": {"type": "float"},
        "inventory_start_date": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        },
        "inventory_end_date": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

This is list of my data:

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "data", "_type" : "_doc" } }
{ "product_code" : "20001", "color_code" : "001", "warehouse_id" : 5, "stock" : 10,"inventory_start_date" : "2019-01-01","inventory_end_date" : "2019-01-04"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "data", "_type" : "_doc" } }
{ "product_code" : "20001", "color_code" : "001", "warehouse_id" : 5, "stock" : 4, "inventory_start_date" : "2019-01-04","inventory_end_date" : "2019-01-07"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "data", "_type" : "_doc" } }
{ "product_code" : "20001", "color_code" : "001", "warehouse_id" : 5, "stock" : 0, "inventory_start_date" : "2019-01-07","inventory_end_date" : "2019-01-07"}
```

inventory_start_date and inventory_end_date keeps the stock amount between 2 dates.

Here is the question: how can I fetch data between 2 date range. For example; fetching documents between 2019-01-05 and 2019-01-06. Or, fetching documents between 2019-01-01 and 2019-01-03.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the documents you've mentioned, if I want the list of the documents with the inventory for e.g. between `2019-01-01` and `2019-01-04`, then I would expand my query **as below** and implement it using [range queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) on two different fields wrapped in a [bool must](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause.

- `inventory_start_date` - in between 2019-01-01 and 2019-01-04
- `inventory_end_date` - in between 2019-01-01 and 2019-01-04

### Query

```
POST myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "inventory_start_date": {
              "gte": "2019-01-01",
              "lte": "2019-01-04"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "inventory_end_date": {
              "gte": "2019-01-01",
              "lte": "2019-01-04"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Response

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 2.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "product_code" : "20001",
          "color_code" : "001",
          "warehouse_id" : 5,
          "stock" : 10,
          "inventory_start_date" : "2019-01-01",
          "inventory_end_date" : "2019-01-04"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Likewise, for any other different date ranges, you would need to construct your query accordingly.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry it does not work as I want. When I want to fetch documents between 2019-01-05 and 2019-01-06, it returns empty. However, there is 2 records with  "inventory_start_date" : "2019-01-04" and "inventory_start_date" : "2019-01-07"

Comment: Are you looking only for querying on `inventory_start_date` and not `inventory_end_date`?

In that case you can simply remove the `inventory_end_date` clause in the above query.

Comment: @oxygen, also if your expected documents are having `inventory_start_date: 2019-01-04` and `inventory_start_date: 2019-01-07`, then these two documents won't be returned when you are querying between `2019-01-05` and `2019-01-06` as mathematically it makes no sense. Perhaps you can update the question with exactly what you are looking for. OTOH, you can try to play around with the query I've mentioned and understand how it works. This would allow you to get the query you are looking for.

Comment: I save new document when a stock amount is updated. Suppose that stock amount is 4 in 2019-01-04 and stock amount is 0 in 2019-01-07. So, I have 2 documents. First one is `"inventory_start_date": "2019-01-04", "stock":"4"` and the other one is  `"inventory_start_date": "2019-01-07", "stock":"0"`.  And I want to search stock status between 2019-01-05 - 2019-01-06. How can I fetch?

Comment: @oxygen Got your query, not sure if ES has a solution for that, but let me do some research and get back to you.